# Function app EventhubTriggered Java, retries and failure

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-java-sdk, azure-java-tools

I am currently working in the Azure function app in java. Here is the scenario:

1. The function app is EventHubTriggered
2. Function app calls the endpoint (HTTPUrlConnection)
3. It gets the response back

Now, if the response is 200 OK then it's fine, else, I'd want to fail the function app so that the Eventhub can retry to trigger this function app.

I was wondering what should the function app do(the method for EventHub trigger is void). Should I throw an exception for it to fail? If yes, then what exception would it be?

Comment: If this answer remains the solution that you use, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will know how you solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Any exception thrown from your function will mark the function as failed.

It does not consider `HttpStatusCode` you return to determine if the function is successful, only whether the function ran successfully to completion without exception. If your function is able to return a response, it is successful from our point of view.

A [retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=java#:%7E:text=A%20retry%20policy%20can%20be%20defined%20for%20a%20specific%20function.) policy can be defined for a specific function. See [Retry policies (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=java#retry-policies-preview) and [Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=java#exceptions-and-return-codes)